# Deleting foreign key in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp, orm, foreign-keys, cakephp-2.x

I want to delete a record in database where it is a foreign key. The below code has been written for product table.

```
public function delete() {
    $id = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
    if( $this->Product->delete( $id )){
        $this->Session->setFlash('Product was deleted');
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    } else {    
        $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to delete product');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

Now what should I do to delete it from master table also?

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`indianautogas1`.`agent_to_consumer`, CONSTRAINT `agent_to_consumer1_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`))
SQL Query: DELETE `Product` FROM `indianautogas1`.`products` AS `Product` WHERE `Product`.`id` = 1
```

Comment: What is master table? How DB record is foreign key? Show Your DB structure.

Comment: Please post the code that defines the relationship between the `Master` and `Product` models.

Comment: The $hasMany, $belongsTo, etc. arrays. Please edit your post and add it there.

Comment: Have you not defined [relationships](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) in your Model files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99106/discussion-between-user-and-inigo-flores).